# Return fields from custom list setting and pass to JS

Tags: apex, javascript, jquery

If I have a custom list setting, 'Info_List__c' with 2 fields, 'Info_Field__c' and 'Info_Name__C'.

What would a method look like that would iterate through the list and return all entries.

And how would I call that method from a VF page and store the results in a JS object?

The returned Object would look as follows if I was to print it into my console:

```
0:Object
    Info_Field__c : "Value"
    Info_Name__C : "Value"
1:Object
    Info_Field__c : "Value"
    Info_Name__C : "Value"
2:Object
    Info_Field__c : "Value"
    Info_Name__C : "Value"
3:Object
    Info_Field__c : "Value"
    Info_Name__C : "Value"
```

Comment: Have you looked into JS Remoting yet ? https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_js_remoting_example.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For easy reference in your JavaScript, I recommend a simple method to return a map of string to object from a remoting method. It would look something like this:

```
@RemoteAction
global static map<string,object> getSettings() {
  return MyListSetting__c.getAll();
}
```